# Django How to create an "order of preference Q" is a survey form

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible using the Django Forms module to have a an order of preference question? Where the users are asked to select a rating for each of the answers? In the below example I would like the user to have to rate the top answer as e.g. 5 and the lowest at 1. Of course it would be great if I could also control the contents and type of metrics in the rating scale.

Below is an example using a MultipleChoiceField but for many of the questions I need to build this will not suffice.

```
from django import forms

#In order of preference which news medium do you access most often?
    RADIO = 'Radio' 
    TV = 'TV'
    NEWSPAPERS = 'Newspaper' 
    ONLINE = 'Online'
    NONE = 'None'

    NEWS_ACCESS = (          
        (RADIO, 'Radio'),
        (TV, 'TV'),
        (NEWSPAPERS, 'Newspaper'), 
        (ONLINE, 'Online'),
        (NONE, 'None'),
                   )

    news_access = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=NEWS_ACCESS, label = 'Which news mediums do you access most often? Select all the apply.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would have a separate field for each of the news access type.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    radio = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    tv = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    newspapers = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    online = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    none = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
```

This will force the user to provide a value for each field. You would then need to use the form [clean_field()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) methods to ensure they are entering the values you expect, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.